# Bluez DBus API to set duplicate filter to disable

Tags: bluetooth, dbus, bluez, bluetooth-device-discovery

How to set scan parameters and disable the filter duplicates, so that I can receive all advertisement from the controller ?
StartDiscovery API only notifies, whenever new device is identified but I want to set filter duplicate to disabled, so that I can receive each and every advertisement from the controller?. 
But I didn't find any DBus API to set the scan parameters nor set scan enable API.

My Goal is simple I need get notify each advertisement received on controller to my client app, How can I do that with Bluez?

Note : I might missing some basic points because new to bluetooth and bluez.

Comment: Can you check this http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt#n48 ?

Comment: @ParthibanN SetDiscoveryFilter provides few options like type, pathloss, rssi, uuids but there is no way to set the duplicate filter option from SetDiscoveryFilter.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no direct filter to apply on the existing devices. You can watch for property changes in existing devices. PropertiesChanged signal will be emitted for the existing devices with new RSSI values. But this applies for proximity. Am not sure what will be the response if the device and adapter are at static location.

Comment: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt#n87

Comment: Comments section is not fine to show my results. So removing this and adding it as "Answer". But not sure still this answers your question.

Comment: Yeah you are right, whenever there is changes in rssi values than PropertyChanged will notified to us, but I need to get notified for each  advertisement received to controller, even if all parameters are same. We have to use low layer(hci) API to achieve this.

Comment: Ya. It may be possible with low level/system calls or HCI calls. Am also new to Bluetooth, may be it will take some time for me to answer it specifically. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In the below output you can see that the Device "Parthiban" is already present under **/org/bluez/hci0/dev_44_D8_84_02_A3_17**. I have started the scan which in turn triggers "StartDiscovery()" method and the same device is updated with RSSI value.

```
root@mx6q:~# bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller 5C:F3:70:6E:26:02 Adapter [default]
**[NEW] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 Parthiban**
[NEW] Device 2C:F0:A2:26:D7:F5 iPhone tteam
[NEW] Device 78:F8:82:10:E7:0C Nexus 5X
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 5C:F3:70:6E:26:02 Discovering: yes
**[CHG] Device 44:D8:84:02:A3:17 RSSI: -52**
```

So you can use "g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe" on the interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" for "PropertiesChanged" signal.

```
while(g_variant_iter_loop(&iter, "{sv}", &property, &value)) {
    if(strcasecmp(property, "RSSI") == 0) {
        /*
         * - Extract the device address from object path
         *  /org/bluez/hci0/dev_44_D8_84_02_A3_17
         *  - Play with the device
         */
    }
```